# How can I use a badge from angular material design doc?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I found a badge [on this page](https://material.angular.io/components/badge/overview). I want to have a digit (I assume, the text "2)) within this nice circle (I'd like to set up a color as well or use some default one): like the very top example from that page.

They say, the code should be:

```
<mat-icon matBadge="22" matBadgePosition="above after">home</mat-icon>
```

But `<div><mat-icon matBadge="22" matBadgePosition="above after">home</mat-icon></div>` doesn't work. I believe I should wrap it inside `<md-content>` and stuff like that, is it a good idea?

In my project I wrap anything inside `<div><md-menu><md-button>`, but right here I can't see this kind of tags.

---

Comment: You're looking at the wrong documentation site.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing up [AngularJS Material](https://material.angularjs.org) with [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io).

Unfortunately, there's no such feature for a badge if you're using AngularJS 1.x Material.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [angular-material-badge](https://github.com/jmouriz/angular-material-badge), which works with AngularJS.